# What is the output element?

Tags: html

Man, I don't get the [output element](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/output) at all.

Q: What is it?

Comment: @cf_PhillipSam You should provide more detail about what aspects you don't understand, in order for us to help you better. If'll save you some downvotes, and it'll save the community some hassle. When I read the documentation, it makes sense to me - what, specifically, is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 4):

The output element is just adding semantic meaning to the markup. It's harder to understand since we are used to the input element which browsers always render using some UI whereas the output element does not have any associated UI (as in a div element).

The onforminput event (as shown in one of the answers) has been deprecated and oninput event should be used instead:

```
<form oninput="result.value=a.valueAsNumber + b.valueAsNumber">
  <input type="range" name="a"> + 
  <input type="number" name="b"> =
  <output name="result"></output>
</form>
```

However, this is only a specific use case of the output tag and it's not necessary that javascript handles the result automatically. Any kind of output even if it's handled manually will suffice.

Answer (score 3):

You would set an `onforminput` event listener to it and then make calculations based on other `input` tags within the same `form` and set its value based on those calculations.

```
<input name="add_me" type="number"> +
<input name="me_too" type="number"> =
<output name="result" onforminput="value = add_me.valueAsNumber + me_too.valueAsNumber"></output>
```

Comment: use oninput instead of onforminput

Comment: @Ernest Not necessarily... not sure why you would correct something that is completely unrelated

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me it's exactly what it says on the tin.  It indicates the result of some calculation done somewhere else on your page.